# Maximize flow through a multigraph, where edges can be added subject to restrictions

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, max-flow, ford-fulkerson

I'm doing a course in algorithms and I'm stuck on this problem.

Given a set of vertices on a grid. Every vertex has a coordinate `(x,y)`.
An source and a sink has been given.
From every vertex there can only be drawn 4 types of edges.

O1: The edge can be drawn from `v1` to `v2` if `v1.x=v2.x` or `v1.y==v1.y`.

O2: The edge can be drawn from `v1` to `v2` if the euclidean distance between `v1` and `v2` is the largest possible.

O3: The edge can be drawn from `v1` to `v2` if there's at least 2 vertices on the line segment between `v1` and `v2`.

O4: The edge can be drawn from `v1` to the sink.

Every vertex has a maximum number for each edge type that can be drawn from it.

Input example for one vertex:

0,1,4,0,2,0 - Is the vertex at coordinate 0,1 where the maximum number of type O1 edges that can be drawn is 4, type O2 is 0, type O3 is 2 and type O4 is 0.

The problem is to find the maximum flow of the graph.

My approach is that if I'm able to generate a weighted directed graph, I can apply Ford-Fulkerson and get the result.
I'm able to generate the graph with all possible edges, but I have no idea how to figure out which edges should be drawn to ensure maximum flow (the restriction on the number of edge types from a given vertex is what trips me up).

I assume that every edge have weight 1, in the resulting multigraph, thus making the maximum flow problem well defined.

Example:

```
0 1 4 0 2 0
2 2 1 2 3 4
4 1 3 1 1 0
4 3 1 0 0 1
6 4 0 0 1 1
9 1 1 0 0 2
9 4 2 0 0 1
9 3 0 0 0 0
```

Possible edges:

[image: Possible edges in example]

Drawn solution:

[image: One possible optimal solution]

I know the answer to this instance of the problem is 5.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249879/discussion-on-question-by-limeeattack-maximize-flow-through-a-multigraph-where).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind my previous answer, think I got it:

Start with the complete graph

Re-write each node into five nodes, one input and then one output of each type

Add nodes from the input node to each output node depending on how many edges of that type the original node was allowed to have

Calculate max flow on the translated graph

So if in your original graph you had a node `n` with `n.O1_out` outgoing neighbors, `n.01_limit` limit, `n.O2_out`, `n.O2_limit`, etc, you'll translate that into:

- An input node `n_input` such that all nodes that previously had edges to `n` now have edges to `n_input`
- An output node `n_O1_output` such that `n_O1_output` has edges to all nodes previously in `n.O1_out` (repeat for `O2`, etc)
- `n.O1_limit` edges (or one edge with `n.O1_limit` weight) going from `n_input` to `n_O1_output` (repeat for `O2`, etc)

Sorry, this is a pain to describe clearly, but does that make sense?

Comment: Fixed that typo

Comment: This approach style is often successful with maximum flow problems.  I haven't tested this, but it feels right.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you!
So since the restrictions are encoded in the rewritten "node-cluster", the edges in the original graph can be assumed to have infinite weight right?

Comment: No, because you might have a limit of `5` of some type, but only `1` actual candidate neighbor

Comment: Wait, nevermind, you could just have five repeated edges. Yes, I think original edges can be treated as infinite weight.

Comment: Thank you once more. I'll mark the answer as correct once I get my implementation working ;)